# Changing html and CSS in Meteor (1.0) packages

Tags: meteor, atmosphere

I want to change some html and css stuff in two Meteor packages,namely in accounts-entry and zurb-foundation packages, but I can't find the html and css files of this packages. What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CSS you can override it in your own CSS file and for HTML use template-extend package. You can't however change the files in the actual packages because they'll get overridden in the next update. You can cline the repo and maintain it separately inside the packages folder without the help of Atmosphere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I use template-extend package?

Answer (score 0):

Your packages file will be downloaded and installed in `~/.meteor/packages` folder and served to your app.

it is not recommended to changes the file inside the packages however you can override the properties inside the app. In case of foundation you can download a [customized version](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation) if you have to do too many changes.